# "500 - Internal server error" when calling ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API on Windows Server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel

I have an ASP .Net Core 2.1 Web API which I've deployed to a new server we recently purchased (running Windows Server 2016 Standard). The API works perfectly on both my development PC and our old server (running Windows Server 2012 R2). But on this new server, I get this error:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I remember a year ago also struggling a lot trying to get it to run on our old server. I did eventually get it to work, but I can't remember what I did! Is there any way to get more information on this error? I've checked the Windows Event Viewer on the new server and there is nothing there. Also, although I've got **stdoutLogEnabled="true"** in my *web.config*, it's not generating the log - and I've created the *\logs\stdout* path so the folders do exist...

I've also got **app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();** in my *Startup.cs*, but I'm not getting any more info that a simple 500 internal server error.

This is what my web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\PropWorx.API.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: cfa62a1f-c5f6-43f8-bcbe-04068e40b803-->
```

I've also got the **Microsoft .NET Core 2.1.1 - Windows Server Hosting** installed and the **Microsoft .NET Core Runtime - 2.1.1** installed (both x86 and x64).

Like I said it works on my development PC and on our old server, so it must be a configuration issue on the new server. Is there a way I can get more detailed error information other than just 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: Try manually running your api from cmd or power shell. Make the call and post the error message here.

Comment: Open a command prompt on the server and run `dotnet.exe MyApp.dll`.See if you get any errors there. If so, you'll be able to see the stacktrace in the command prompt window. If not, then it's an IIS issue. Assumiing you've correctly installed the hosting bundle, ensure that you either restarted the server afterwards, or completely restarted the IIS service (`iisreset` isn't enough).

Comment: Thanks Edward and Chris. I ran the API on the server using DOTNET RUN from the command prompt (does that run it in IIS or IIS Express??), and I called on of its endpoints using Postman on (also from the server, calling  https://localhost:5001/api/test). It seems like everything is working fine - I can see the SQL queries being generated and executed by EF Core on the command prompt window. But nothing gets back to Postman. Postman just times out... yet everything seems fine on the command prompt. It doesn't show any errors... so strange..

Answer (score 4):

I had an outdated version of the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle. I had version 2.1.1 installed. I removed it, and installed version 2.1.4 and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Various reasons can cause this issue.

if this is happening only in the browser (working with curl or postman), it can be a pre-flight request error, then you will need to modify UrlScan.ini (I assume this didn't changed on Windows 2016) at the following path (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\urlscan), add OPTIONS to [AllowVerbs].

if not, make sure you followed the steps provided in Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

You may need to install [Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable on the server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)

To get logs, change "IncludeScopes": true, in your appsettings.json logging section, check also the event viewer.

Comment: Thanks KYG. Yes, I did install the Visual C++ 2015. I tried running the API locally on the server using DOTNET RUN (not sure if that runs it in IIS or IIS Express), and testing it with Postman on the server. It seems like everything is working fine - I can see the SQL queries being generated and executed by EF Core when I call the action. But nothing gets back to Postman. Postman just times out... yet everything seems fine on the command prompt. It doesn't show any errors... so strange...

Comment: Also, even though I modified the web.config to include stdoutLogEnabled="true", and created the corresponding folders in stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout", and added "IncludeScopes": true to the loggin section of appsettings.json, it's not logging anything. It's not even logging any errors on the Event Viewer. :/

Comment: You're welcome, what is the setup for LogLevel in your appsettings.json? what is the returned HTTP code in postman now? if you don't get logs, that means you don't have any warnings or errors while executing a request, to see all the logs you need to change Default to "Information".

Comment: I noticed one thing... on IIS on the server, when going to my site, and trying to open any of the links, such as "Error Pages" or "Logging" or any of the shortcuts on IIS, it gives this error:

\\?\C:\inetpub\propworxapi\web.config

Comment: My default LogLevel in appsettings.json was "Warning". I have changed it now to "Information" but it's still not logging anything. But my guess is because there are no errors. I think the API is executing perfectly. I suspect it's simply that the reply from the API is not reaching the client (Postman in this case). On postman, it doesn't even get a return HTTP status code.... Postman simply seems to time out waiting for a response. And when I run the API manually from cmd using DOTNET BUILD, everything seems to execute properly... No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Using Jexus Manager, the error seems to be "Unrecognized configuration path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/.'

Comment: well in this case try to change the argument attribute within the aspNetCore tag in you web.config file, to a full path (C:\inetpub\propworxapi\PropWorx.API.dll).